# How to send args to flask function?

Tags: python, flask, routes, args

I need to send arg to my flask function but I have 'missing 1 required positional argument' error. What I should do to solve this problem.

```
check = True
@app.route('/sortbysalary', methods=['POST'])
def sortbysalary(check):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if check is True:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('employees.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            with conn:
                # no case carre
                c.execute("SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY pay COLLATE NOCASE DESC")
            query = c.fetchall()
            check = False
            print(check)
        else:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('employees.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            with conn:
                # no case carre
                c.execute("SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY pay COLLATE NOCASE ASC")
            query = c.fetchall()
            check = True
            print(check)
        return render_template('show.html', query=query)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to pass the 'check' variable to this view function from another route, a common way of doing so is using the route decorator. I.e.:

```
@app.route('/sortbysalary/<check>', methods=['POST'])
def sortbysalary(check):
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can use Flask's session to do that which is more secure. Not sure if any of this applies here though.